# What makes the 'Request Entity Too Large' error when sending an image to Telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

File size: 51.2 KB
Trying to send:

```py
>>> send_img_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto'
>>> img_name = 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/WhatsApp Image 2019-05-30 at 20.54.40.jpeg'
>>> r = requests.post(send_img_url, data={'chat_id': '-351543550', 'photo': open(img_name, 'rb')})
>>> r
<Response [413]>
>>> r.reason
'Request Entity Too Large'
>>> r.content
b''
>>>
```

Also i try some another requests like:

```py
photo = open(('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/WhatsAppImage.jpeg').encode('utf-8'), 'rb')
r = requests.post(send_img_url, data={'chat_id': '-351543550', 'photo': photo})
```

and:

```py
 with io.open('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/WhatsAppImage.jpeg', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    r = requests.post(send_img_url, data={'chat_id': '-351543550', 'photo': f})
```

Last option give me next error:

```py
>>> r
<Response [400]>
>>> r.reason
'Bad Request'
```

Comment: You can't parse an image as UTF8.

Comment: @SLaks so what i must to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably doing it wrong.

As [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) docs says:

> Post the file using **multipart/form-data** in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.

[In requests lib](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), by using `data=` keyword argument, you're sending payload using `form-encoded` type, not `multipart/form-data`.

Try to make your request like that:

```py
import requests


chat_id = '-351543550'
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto?chat_id={}'.format(chat_id)
filepath = 'C:\correct\path\to\your\file.jpg'
r = requests.post(url, files={"photo": open(filepath, 'rb')})  # note: files, not data
print(r.status_code)
```

P.S.: you can also send `chat_id` as `form-encoded` param by using

```py
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sendPhoto'
...
r = requests.post(url, data={'chat_id': '-351543550'}, files={"photo": open(filepath, 'rb')})
```

Comment: both options give me error:400
>>> r.reason
'Bad Request'
>>>

Comment: and what is the output of `r.text`?

Comment: well, that's my mistake. this afternoon, the group where I am sending messages was one ID going now the other. I did not know that they are changing.

Comment: anyway you should use `files=`, otherwise you'll still receive `413 entity too large`

Comment: ty, but can u tell me why ID group was changed? is it does always?

Comment: it's diffucult to guess, maybe group settings were chaged or something like that

Answer (score 2):

**Using a Local Bot API Server you can send a large file up to 2GB.**

GitHub Source Code:

> https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api

Official Documentation

> https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server

You can `build and install` this to your server by following the instructions on this link https://tdlib.github.io/telegram-bot-api/build.html

basic setup :

1. Generate Telegram Applications id from https://my.telegram.org/apps
2. Start the server `./telegram-bot-api --api-id=<your-app-id> --api-hash=<your-app-hash> --verbosity=20`
3. Default address is http://127.0.0.1:8081/ and the port is 8081.
4. All the official APIs will work with this setup. Just change the address to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME` reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Example Code with:

```js
import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/bot<your-bot-token>/sendVideo"

payload={'chat_id': 'chat_id',
'supports_streaming': 'true'}
files=[
  ('video',('your_file_name.mp4',open('path_of_file','rb'),'application/octet-stream'))
]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution proposed by Ivan Vinogradov did not work due to Cyrillic filenames. Changing the paths to Latin fixed it.

Comment: Can you provide an example here?